# How to Apply Update to Multiple Sprites Not Created in didMove()

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm creating multiple enemy sprites with a function outside of didMove(). Code:

```
func spawnEnemies() {
    var enemy = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "triangle")
    enemy.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height - 100)
    enemy.name = "enemy";
    enemy.zPosition = 6.0;

    enemy.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false

    enemy.zRotation = 0
    enemy.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    enemy.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: enemy.texture!, size: enemy.texture!.size())
    enemy.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    enemy.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
    enemy.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = enemyCategory
    enemy.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = blockerCategory
    enemy.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = blockerCategory
    enemy.setScale(CGFloat(0.05))
    addChild(enemy)
}
```

I want to use an extension on each and every one of the sprites created by the function within update(). Extension code:

```
extension SKNode {
func rotateVersus(destPoint: CGPoint) {
    let v1 = CGVector(dx:0, dy:1)
    let v2 = CGVector(dx:destPoint.x - position.x, dy: destPoint.y - position.y)
    let angle = atan2(v2.dy, v2.dx) - atan2(v1.dy, v1.dx)
    zRotation = angle
       }
}
```

Update() code:

```
override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    enemy.rotateVersus(destPoint: blocker.position)
}
```

I defined enemy within the GameScene like so:

```
lazy var enemy = SKSpriteNode()
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Use enumerateChildNodes().

Comment: Where do you call spawnEnemies()?

Comment: I've never tried using enumerateChildNodes() before. Could you help explain a little better? @El Tomato

Comment: Within didMove() @sabi

Comment: You can create an `SKNode` "container" in `GameScene` to hold your enemies, add your enemies to the container (instead of the scene), add the container to the scene, and iterate over the children of the container.